Docker container exiting with "Port 5000 is already in use" error, but no process is using it on the host
I am trying to run a Node.js application in a Docker container, but the container keeps exiting with the error: "Port 5000 is already in use." However, when I check the host machine, no process is using port 5000.
Error Logs from Container:
Server is running on port 5000
Port 5000 is already in use
What I’ve Tried:
a.Verified no process is using port 5000 on the host:
Ran ss -tuln | grep 5000 and lsof -i :5000, but both commands returned no results.
b.Tried using a different host port:
Ran the container with docker run -d -p 6000:5000 -e PORT=5000, but the error persists.

Can you run the container successfully on another machine? You could spin up a vm to try this out. Can you provide us with a reproducible example? It's possible the problem is with the application configuration in your container.

When you say "Error Logs from Container:", does that maybe mean the error is the port 5000 is already in use inside the container? Without seeing your Dockerfile or your Actions workflow file, there's not much we can do to help, can you share them with us? (Edit your question and add them as code blocks.)
